# Debugger cannot intercept certain exceptions when BeingDebugged is patched to 0

Tags: debugging, winapi

I wrote a small Win32 debugger tool to test Anti-Debug tricks. It works well except for certain scenarios:

In my test app, I call `NtCloseHandle` inside of a `try`/`except` block with an invalid handle value. I noticed that in this case, my debugger doesn't receive the `EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE` exception, however other exceptions (breakpoints, for instance) are working fine.

Further investigation showed that this happens only when the `_PROCESS_ENVIRONMENT_BLOCK` is patched so that `PEB->BeingDebugged` is `0` (which I'm doing to make `IsDebuggerPresent` return false). This is part of the Anti-Debug testing.

When I disable this patch operation, my debugger *does* receive `EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE`, so my question is: How can I receive this exception even with `PEB->BeingDebugged` patched to `0`?

Comment: You can not. You not think that exception not raised in this case ?

Comment: @RbMm I think maybe there is way to bypass it. OK only way is patch NtCloseHandle. Thanks.